# Compare same value from array in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two arrays content another array. How can check same value from this?

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 36 [1] => 43 [2] => 47 [3] => 51 [4] => 52 [5] => 54 [6] => 56 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 38 [1] => 44 [2] => 47 [3] => 50 [4] => 53 [5] => 55 [6] => 57 ) ) 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => 57 [2] => 54 [3] => 52 [4] => 51 [5] => 44 [6] => 47 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 54 [1] => 57 [2] => 51 [3] => 53 [4] => 47 [5] => 43 [6] => 39 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => 57 [2] => 53 [3] => 51 [4] => 48 [5] => 44 [6] => 38 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => 53 [2] => 51 [3] => 47 [4] => 44 [5] => 37 [6] => 57 ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first merge each array, use + or array_merge for the index is number not string. then you can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$temp = [];
foreach($arr1 as $arr)
{
  $temp += $arr;
}
$array1 = $temp;

var_dump(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
```

Comment: this can't for array in array...

Comment: yup! i use foreach then i use array_intersect. thanks

Comment: i also used this

if($array1 === array_intersect($array1, $array2) && $array2 === array_intersect($array2, $array1)) {
    echo 'Equal';
} else {
    echo 'Not equal';
}